# Make a SQL query with wpdb in WordPress

Tags: wp-query, functions, wpdb, sql

mates, please can you help me with the following sql query attempt. This query controls whether a person has performed a form action for 24 hours.

This is the SQL:

```
SELECT min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `fecha_inscripcion`, now())) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `field_name`="cedula" and `field_value` = "1144093762"
```

This is the result:

```
min(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `fecha_inscripcion`, now()))
5
```

[image]

Now, in WordPress I did so

```
global $wpdb;
$day = 'DAY';
$now = 'now()';
$fieldvalue = '1144093762';
$fieldname = 'cedula';

$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT min(TIMESTAMPDIFF($day,$wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits.fecha_inscripcion, $now))
    FROM  $wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits
    WHERE field_name=$fieldname and field_value=$fieldvalue");

print_r($post_count);
echo "Resultado"+$post_count;
```

But it returns me in 0, when it should be 5 in this case.

Thank

Comment: What do you get when you echo `$wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits.fecha_inscripcion`

Comment: @czerspalace Hi, It is a mistake I made, the thought that has to call the field of a table that way. haha

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is how you're specifying the custom table name (e.g., `$wpdb->cf7dbplugin_submits`).

`$wpdb` only knows about the "built-in" tables when accessing a table name via `$wpdb->xxx`.  To specify access a custom table name, use `{$wpdb->prefix}custom_table_name`.

The other thing I notice is that, for security purposes, you should **never** use interpolated variables
in an SQL statement passed to any of the `$wpdb` query methods.  Instead, you should use [$wpdb->prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Putting these 2 things together results in:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare (
    "SELECT min(TIMESTAMPDIFF($day,`fecha_inscripcion`, $now))
    FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}cf7dbplugin_submits
    WHERE field_name=%s and field_value=%s",
    $fieldname,
    $fieldvalue
    ) ;
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var ($sql) ;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my friend, and for your time. Now If I want to prove that the query actually does, should I store a value as a variable in $fieldname and $fieldvalue? for example: $fieldname = '111'... Thanks.

Comment: @iDuruiz I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment...can you clarify?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I do not speak English well, I already verified that the query works, but without using the "TIMESTAMPDIFF ..."I am not sure if it is because I am using wrong the TIMESTAMPDIFF, can you explain me how to use this function in the right way? thank you

Comment: I have solved it, thanks to you, you're the best. 
Thanks to you, you're the best. thank, thank much.

Answer (score 0):

I attach the solution, thank a Paul 'Sparrow Hawk' Biron

```
global $wpdb;
$day = 'DAY';
$now = 'now()';
$fieldname = "cedula";
$fieldvalue = "1144092";

// set the meta_key to the appropriate custom field meta key

$sql = $wpdb->prepare (
    "SELECT min(TIMESTAMPDIFF($day,fecha_inscripcion, $now))
    FROM  {$wpdb->prefix}cf7dbplugin_submits
    WHERE field_name=%s and field_value=%s",
    $fieldname,
    $fieldvalue
    );
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var($sql) ;

echo "<p>User count is {$post_count}</p>";
```